# Where to extract the source code (.cpp files) of wxWidgets under Linux Mint 19 for step inside debugging?

Tags: c++, linux, wxwidgets, linux-mint

I have successfully installed the wxWidgets v3.1.1 banaries from CodeLite's website [Here](http://codelite.org/LiteEditor/WxWidgets31Binaries)

The problem is the installation has no .cpp files for step inside debugging.
So I had to download the source code to get the .cpp files.

My question is where to extract them in the system?

Thank you.

Comment: Github maybe? https://github.com/wxWidgets/wxWidgets

Comment: You will probably have to compile those source files yourself and use resulting binaries, so that all debug symbols will be created, and correct location for source files recorded.

Comment: @Tomay, keep in mind that most likely the binaries you used initially might be compiled without the debugging symbols. So as noted by SergeyA, the best option is to compile the library yourself and don't install it. They won't be conflicting with the original ones you already have, since you will be using them for development and not to run the CodeLite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract them anywhere you want, just use gdb `directory` command to add the path to this directory to the list of directories that gdb searches for the source files.

You can also find `set substitute-path` gdb command useful when using binaries from a different system.

Comment: I ended up extracting it in my home folder "~/devel", and I added it to the gdb debugger search dirs in the C::B project properties. and it worked. My first thought was "/usr/src"